# Django virtual environment

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv

What is the proper way of adding an already existing Django project to a newly created virtual environment? Do I just move the project to the virtual environment root directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the directory is - the only important thing is that you activate the virtual environment every time you want to work on the project.

I personally prefer to have the project directory inside the virtual env directory, but that is not required.

One caveat: don't put the virtual env inside your project directory. That may cause problems with test discovery and with git.

Comment: The lovely virtualenvwrapper makes this divorce explicit by separating PROJECT_DIR and VIRTUALENV_DIR.